# How to stop a user to see restricted page in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Asp.net and I don't have much knowledge about it. I have one query.

My dotnet application URL is http://www.example.com

For my website's internal behavior, I send request on http://www.example.com/net/afk/xyz and a response displays on the web page.  And this path not shows on the web browser URL. it only shows http://www.example.com/page

But my problem is, when if someone enters directly http://www.example.com/net/afk/xyz into the web browser after the login in my application, then this also gets open and user can see my all information which I dont want to show.

I want something - url http://www.example.com/net/afk/xyz should work internally but could not be launch via the web browser URL.

I tried to enter some Denied rule as 'net\afk in IIS but for those, my url http://www.example.com/net/afk/xyz stops to respond internally.

Please help me what I can do with this. Is this type of requirement is possible?

Comment: Could you post your routeConfig.cs code for more help.Regarding the second issue you can use asp .net mvc Authorization filter to avoid such scenarios

Comment: I dont have any routeConfig.cs, I have just web.config.

Comment: Check in the app_Start Folder in your project.

Comment: Are you using Roles in your admin panel ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, if you want your page should not open directly by Url then you can do it by this way

```
Uri u = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (u != null)
            return true;
        else
        {
            //Here user try to hit your Page url directly
            //Then you can redirect that user to your default Page or Home Page
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you need is to prevent the user from accessing the url directly. This can be achieved by using mvc's attributes which can be applied onto controllers, action methods and so on. So for this you will create a NoDirectAccessAttribute which will prevent the user from navigating to the action method.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace TestProject
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class NoDirectAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null ||
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host != filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                               RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "" }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this can be applied to your action method as follows:

```
[NoDirectAccess]
public ActionResult xyz()
{
    return View();
}
```

If the user attempts to access this action method, he will then be rerouted to the homepage, as specified in the NoDirectAccessAttribute class. However, you will still be able to navigate the user to this action method internally.